# I want to know how "inotifywait" trace file's operation

Tags: file-io, linux-kernel, filesystems

I used "inotifywait" to trace the file's operation. I want to know its structure. How does it know that a file is created, read and deleted? How does it know that a directory is created and removed? What are kernel's files that inotifywait tracks. Which kernel's files doing these file's operation? Please help me find out. Thank you.

Comment: Ref. [fsnotify.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/notify/fsnotify.c), which is used by inotify these days, AFAIK. Anyway, to really know how it works involves getting nice and dirty with the source/kernel/VFS: "[`fsnotify`] is the main call to fsnotify.  The VFS calls into hook specific functions in linux/fsnotify.h. Those functions then in turn call here .."

Answer (score 1):

inotify is a feature built into the kernel (first included in version  2.6.13). Since a file create request or a file close (on write complete) request needs to go through the kernel, it is implicitly aware of all these operations. Same goes for directories, since the kernel is aware if the file created is a directory or not.

> Which kernel's files doing these file's operation?

Are you asking for the inotify source code? You could possible start by looking at the header files here: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/ (inotify.h)